# Asp.net and Facebook authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth

I'd like to do the following:

- Allow users to register in my asp.net site using their facebook credentials.
- Retrieve facebook client information. Like (Name, surname, email address etc). So I can import this information into my application.
- Allow users to log into my site using facebook credentials.

I've been searching and have come across these options:

- Facebook.net SDK
- dotnetoauth
- Facebook Connect
- Graph API

I'm confused as to which would be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this resource offers a good tutorial on how to integrate with Facebook's user infrastructure:

http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/

There is also this code example / framework which takes you though much of the process:

http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/

And this walkthrough which is a little more up-to-date:

http://area72.ro/general-it/how-to-login-via-facebook-in-asp-net.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement your solution would be to use the javascript SDK for this.

You add a Facebook Login button which the user clicks on and authorizes your website giving you access to his information. This basically skips the need for registration for facebook users since the registration is the actual login process.

When the user has authorized your website (thus logged in and registered) you have access to his information which you can use to store in your users database using his faceboook id as a key. You can access the user's information sending an http request to the graph api https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id which will return a json object with the users information.

Other then the facebook login you will want a standard login, registration form for users without facebook.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/